# PHP Decode Base64, Refresh and Keep data

Tags: java, php, android

I have an image that I upload with a HTTP Post method to my webserver written in PHP.
My code compresses a bitmap to a jpeg coded byte array and sends that Base64 encoded to the server which decodes, writes it to a file and opens it as a jpg image.

Index.php:

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
echo $base;
// base64 encoded utf-8 string
$binary=base64_decode($base);
// binary, utf-8 bytes
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
// print($binary);
//$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
?>
```

and I have an empty 0kb test.jpg in the same directory.

Sometimes I can see the image when I quickly press F5(refresh), but then when I refresh again, the image is removed again and it's again 0KB. (working on Google Chrome)

1) How can I make that the picture keeps displaying the data written to test.jpg and doesn't change back to 0kb? So when I view it, the picture is still there. (note that my PHP knowledge is not so good, so instructions would be really much appreciated.)

Upload method in JAVA, Android:

```
public void uploadFrame(byte[] Frame, String WebClient) {
    String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(mCurrentFrame);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
    ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

       try{

           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new
           HttpPost(WebClient);
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
     }
}
```

2) Another question is, if this method is actually safe because people could send any POST Method data to it and display any picture. So how would this work in PHP to first check if a parameter in JAVA is equal to a parameter in your PHP code, so only people with the same parameter could upload this code to his webserver.

This could be a quite intresting topic for some people.

EDIT:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_REQUEST['image'])) {
        $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
        echo $base;
        // base64 encoded utf-8 string
        $binary=base64_decode($base);
        // binary, utf-8 bytes
        header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
        // print($binary);
        //$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);
        $file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
        fwrite($file, $binary);
        fclose($file);
        echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
    }

        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        readfile('test.jpg');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you refresh the page, it's going to write data to that `test.jpg` file. If you don't submit a base64 image, it'll just write out a blank/null string, which means a 0-byte file.

Instead, try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['image'])) {
   ... your decoding/fopen/fwrite stuff here ...
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg')
readfile('test.jpg');
```

This will directly output the image as a jpg, rather than outputting HTML and forcing the browser to open yet another HTTP connection to load the .jpg file.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your quick reply! I tried this, but this doesn't seem to work: <?php

  if (isset($_REQUEST['image'])) {
      $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
   echo $base;
   // base64 encoded utf-8 string
   $binary=base64_decode($base);
   // binary, utf-8 bytes
   header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
   // print($binary);
   //$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);
   $file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
   fwrite($file, $binary);
   fclose($file);
   echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
  }

   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   readfile('test.jpg');
  ?> note that my php sucks :s

Comment: Please don't put code snippets into comments. they're impossible to read. From what little my acheing eyes can see, you're outputting two content-type headers.

Comment: Yea, Ok, I'm sorry. new to Stackoverflow. I will edit the topic above add it at the bottom. Thanks for taking your intrest is this.

Comment: Although, the picture MUST be displayed on the webbrowser, cause this is for some kind of live streaming. It would be useless if people have to download these files. :s

Comment: the header/readfile will display it in-browser. It just elmiinates the extra step of the browser parsing your html snippet and firing up a new http request to fetch the file.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Another thing would be that it refreshes immediatly when there comes an image from 0kb to xkb. This way if people want to watch the live streaming, they don't have to refresh the page until it actually starts and shows the image. You understand this? :s

Comment: Ah. then you'd need to output some html with a meta refresh or similar to force the browser to reload.

Comment: Ok, I have finally found on how to output and show the picture, but I have still one problem. So now, the picture is shown on my screen, but when I redo this method, refresh, the same picture is still shown and there weren't any bytes changed on the server side. :s How do I overwrite the image now with a new image?

Answer (score 1):

Answering question 2:

No, it is not safe.  You should really probably sign it or outright encrypt it in transit to ensure you can trust the data you get -- it's either yours, or garbage.  Check out [`mcrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) for more info on that.

Comment: Hey, Thank your for this info. However I'm also looking for something that checks if a parameter in my JAVA code is equal to a code in my PHP, that way, I can select a user and give him the permission( by giving him the parameter), so he can send it.

Comment: Include it in the encrypted portion so you won't be vulnerable to spoofing or MITM attacks =)  **edit: *as* vulnerable**

Comment: Ok, thanks, problem 2 would be solved. Although, Have you an idea of how this will look like in php with the parameter thing. I think I might solve the mcrypt("Thanks for this :D")

Answer (score 0):

Quick caveat: if you're setting the header to me a bitmap, dont write HTML to the screen: (`echo '<img src=test.jpg>';`)

I would echo the header to be `image/jpeg` and then just write the raw binary to the screen.